# how to modify image changer ajax script

Tags: html, ajax, image

i have a script that changes the current image with the selected image but i need to insert an attribute so that it targets the image tag with only that class

CODE----

```
      <script>
   $(function(){
      Test = {
           UpdatePreview: function(obj){
        // if IE < 10 doesn't support FileReader
         if(!window.FileReader){
         // don't know how to proceed to assign src to image tag
         } else {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var target = null;

            reader.onload = function(e) {
           target =  e.target || e.srcElement;
           $("img").attr(".the_pre_prev").prop("src", target.result);// tried $("img").attr("CLASS NAME").prop("src", target.result)
         };
          reader.readAsDataURL(obj.files[0]);
      }
    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target an image with an specific class, you can simply do (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
$("img.the-class").attr("src", target.result)
```

See the [jQuery class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) for reference.